# Edit database structure field name and field restrictions in Java using Netbeans

Tags: database, netbeans, derby

I am sorry for this dummy question.

I have a database structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "CLIENT" (
  "AFM" INTEGER not null primary key,
  "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR(30),
  "LASTNAME" VARCHAR(30),
  "ADDRESS" VARCHAR(30),
  "PHONE" INTEGER,
  "MAIL" VARCHAR(60)
);
```

Questions:

1) when i press : "Run SQL" button on Netbeans, the database is created. If i edit e field, e.g. the field "Mail" to "Email", i press again the same button but i get an error as the database is already existed. How can i edit name of fields on database?

2) As you can see above, i want the field "LASTNAME" to be consisted of <30 chars. If i want the same for the field:  "AFM" INTEGER ?? If i write:  "AFM" INTEGER(10) i get an error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `integer(10)` is **not** a standard SQL datatype (and doesn't do what you want in MySQL either). To limit the values of an integer type you need to use a check constraint. Check the manual of your DBMS for details.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. Actually, i have installed the Netbeans IDE and i start a Java DB(embedded) connection with my database. Which DBMS could you offer me to use?

Comment: JavaDB is just a re-branded Apache Derby. The manuals can be found here: http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/index.html

Comment: Btw: the above statement does not create "a database". It creates a **table**. A "database" is the whole collection of tables that you create.

Answer (score 2):

In order to limit the values for a numeric column you need to use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT 
(
    AFM INTEGER not null primary key,
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(30),
    PHONE INTEGER,
    MAIL VARCHAR(60),
    constraint check_afm check (afm <= 10)
);
```

Although I fail to see what reason you could have to limit the values of a primary key column.

If that table already exists, you will get an error. If you don't yet have data in the table (or you don't mind losing it), you can simply drop it using:

```
drop table client;
```

The run the above CREATE TABLE.

Otherwise (if you want to preserve the data) you need an alter table statement:

```
alter table client 
  add constraint check_afm check (afm <= 10);
```

Note that this will fail if there are any rows in the table violating that check constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to limit the integers becouse for example, the afm field i want to be <10 digits long. The same could be for example for an identification card number which is contained by a fixed number of digits.

Comment: @Limas less than 10 **digits** is something different than `< 10`. To ensure a limit of 10 *digits*  you need to use `<= 999999999`

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot create a table twice. If the table already exists you need to use an "[alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)" to change fieldnames.

2) Which error do you get? As a sidenote: Integer(n) defines the display width (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html)) and not the value range, in case you were not aware of this fact.